# Implementing BackgroundWorker.ReportProgess() with System.Threading.Tasks.Task

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

How can we achieve the functionality of **ReportProgress** in **BackgroundWorker** class for a thread to return back updates to main thread using the **Task** class (in .NET 4.0)?

What I am trying to achieve is to create a thread which would monitor few files and report back the modified date time stamp to the main thread whenever those files are updated.

Comment: Have you taken a look to class `FileSystemWatcher`?

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking at a generic resolution since my source can vary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the UI thread's `SynchronizationContext` and call `Post` to run delegates asynchronously on the UI thread.

Comment: Actually I don't have a UI thread as I am spawning thread from an EXE. I am trying to achieve the functionality similar to BackgroundWorker class. Will it be possible to achieve the above with a non-UI thread too?

Comment: @Thinkster: If you don't have a UI thread, you need to create some mechanism to act as a UI thread.  (a message pump)

Comment: @Thinkst - that makes it a non-question. The BackgroundWorker is entirely UI oriented.

Comment: Ok. But is there something else which I can try apart from creating the message pump?

Comment: @Henk: True but as I mentioned, I am trying to achieve a similar functionality in Non-UI based threads.

Comment: @Thinkster: You cannot magically inject code into a thread; you need the thread to explicitly run the code.  You can do that using thread-safe multicast delegate the way C# 4 events work.  I did that once, but I don't have the code on me right now.

Comment: @Slaks: I was trying to find out if there is a parallel to ReportProgress for Non-UI threads and I believe its not. Thanks.

Comment: You can create a task, flag it as long running and create a SynchronizationContext. Then you can other threads pass delegates to that object and it will schedule the work to be sequentially on the thread. Or something along those lines.